# Compilador "Roslyn" já está disponível no CodeDom?

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-compiler-platform

Gostaria de saber se o Compilador Microsoft Roslyn já está disponível na namespace `System.CodeDom` do .NET Framework... Se não estiver, como eu referencio esse compilador no meu projeto?